# How to parse a DateTime string in format '2014-10-02T12:00:00' as local?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime, cross-browser

If I call this in **Firefox (32)** or **IE (11)**, it will be parsed as local time:

```
new Date('2014-10-02T12:00:00')
```

However, if I parse it in **Chrome (37.0.2062.124 m 64-bit)**, it will be parsed as **UTC time**.

How can I parse it as local time uniformly across all browsers?

Comment: Try this http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Why not append the timezone offset to the end as defined by _ISO 8601_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date-time-string-format), this is, in fact, a valid date format, but a bug may have been the cause for the original discrepant browser behavior.

Try using the time zone indicator from [ISO 8601 date standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (append a `Z` to the end of the timestamp), and see if that helps.

Honorable mention: [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is wonderful for parsing dates, but it’s a hefty lib so that comes with its own trade-offs.

Comment: The statement "*That's not a valid date format,*" is incorrect. It's a valid ISO 8601 format for a local timestamp. It's also valid per [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) and *should* be parsed as local. There is no need for a library (though they are helpful for parsing in general).

Comment: Did this change recently? It’s a 5yo answer, and if it changed around this time it would for the browser discrepancy.

Comment: The format was always valid ISO 8601 and [*valid ECMAScript*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) since 2011 (Ed 5.1 aka ES5). It was a bug in Chrome that has since been fixed, but advice is not to trust the built–in parser. Safari's parser still has bugs with standard (ECMA-262) formats and there are differences between browsers for non–standard formats.